# Use substr until condition is met

Tags: r, conditional-statements, symbols, substr

I have a vector from which I just need the first word. The words have different lengths. Words are separated by a symbol (. and _) How can I use the `substr()` function to get a new vector with just the first word?

I was thinking of something like this

```
x <- c("wooombel.ab","mugran.cd","friendly_ef.ab","hungry_kd.xy")
y <- substr(x,0, ???)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `sub` with some regular expressions would be the easiest solution:

```
sub(pattern = "[._].*", replacement = "", x = x)
# [1] "wooombel" "mugran"   "friendly" "hungry"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sapply(strsplit(x,'[._]'), function(x) x[1])
[1] "wooombel" "mugran"   "friendly" "hungry"
```

Comment: Or `sapply(strsplit(x,'[._]'), "[", 1)`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use package `stringr`.  It has some really handy functions for string manipulation.

One that comes to mind for this problem is `word`.  It has a `sep` argument that allows the use of a regular expression.

```
> x <- c("wooombel.ab","mugran.cd","friendly_ef.ab","hungry_kd.xy")
> library(stringr)
> word(x, sep = "[._]")
# [1] "wooombel" "mugran"   "friendly" "hungry"
```

Another option that allows you to continue to use `substr` is `str_locate`.  So if we just subtract 1 from its result, we can get the desired first words.

```
> substr(x, 1, str_locate(x, "[._]")-1)
# [1] "wooombel" "mugran"   "friendly" "hungry"
```

Answer (score 1):

An extraction approach with `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(x, "[a-z]+(?=[._])")

## [1] "wooombel" "mugran"   "friendly" "hungry"
```

Though `"[^a-z]+(?=[._])"` may be more explicit.

[**Regex explanation:**](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl)

```
[^a-z]+                  any character except: 'a' to 'z' (1 or
                         more times)
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  [._]                     any character of: '.', '_'
)                        end of look-ahead
```